# MySQL: Utilizar "ñ" en el nombre de una columna

Tags: mysql, codificación

Estoy intentando importar una base de datos desde un archivo sql. La base de datos tiene esta tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE `unidades_equipo` (
  `idUnidadEquipo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `apellidos` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `años` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `prioridad` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `disponibilidad` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `experiencia` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `observaciones` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCategoriaEquipo` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Al copiar eso a la CLI me sale este error: `ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'a\xA4os'`

He intentado cambiar a utf8_spanish_ci pero tampoco me funciona.

**EDIT**

Al final he decidido cambiar las eñes, aunque si alguien necesita mantenerlas, he conseguido importarla poniendo `años` sin las tildes ` o desde phpMyAdmin

Comment: Pues he probado en una base de datos de MARIADB con el cliente HeidiSQL y me la crea sin problema

Comment: No usar utf8 en MySql, en su defecto utf8mb4 es el [estándar de facto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/581584/80870) hoy en día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cámbiale las eñes en el script. Es el modo más fácil de resolver el problema, de lo contrario tendrás que hacer reconfiguraciones en el servidor de la BBDD, y eso no es buena idea.

No es recomendable usar caracteres extendidos de ningún idioma dentro de los objetos de la base, ni tampoco espacios en blanco. tienden a generar errores de este tipo.

Comment: El problema es que esa BBDD la tiene que utilizar una aplicación que me han pasado, y si le cambio las eñes a la BBDD probablemente me fallen algunas consultas de la aplicación.

Comment: Tal como te mencionan, el estándar está contemplado para **no usar caracteres** como la ñ en el nombramiento de las tablas. Si el aplicativo las usa en las consultas, debes modificar los script también en el código del aplicativo. Así te evitas problemas posteriores.

Comment: Exactamente como te lo comenta también DjCrazy, es preferible modificar el aplicativo para corregir defectos de diseño antes que el problema se extienda en el tiempo y cause más inconvenientes.
A pesar que los editores de DBMS soporten el uso de caracteres extendidos, no es una buena práctica y usualmente los desarrolladores lo saben. La solución eficiente es ajustarse a lo que el estandar establece.