# agregue caracteres especiales directos a base de datos mysql y no logro decodificarlos en php

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un problema, se agregaron palabras con acentos directamente a mysql, el problema es que ahora las quiero mostrar en php y me salen con signos de ?, entonces no se si las tengo que subir por php codificadas o que hacer, en php y mysql esta todo en utf8, si me pudieran ayudar, no se si con     mb_convert_encoding($subcategoria, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8'); se podrá hacer algo

Comment: Si está en tu posibilidad, pon tus tablas de mysql en **utf8mb4_general_ci**. UTF8mb4 es *"el estándar"* de hoy en día.

Comment: Si mi respuesta aporto una solucion a tu duda, recuerda marcala como resuelta.

Answer (score 3):

Existe una serie de propiedades y cosas que se deben tener en cuenta al trabajar con bases de datos y en especial con caracteres especiales:

---

### Estructura/declaración de la base de datos y tablas:

***Base de Datos:***
`CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` y `COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci`

quedaria asi:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `tu_base_de_datos` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

**Nota:** `utf8` esta deprecado y se aconseja usar su variante `utf8mb4*` [Link Documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html#:%7E:text=The%20utf8mb3%20character%20set%20is,Beginning%20with%20MySQL%208.0.)

Esto también aplica para las tablas en donde tendríamos algo así:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tu_tabla` (
  ...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

**Nota:** nótese la diferencia en donde para la base de datos uso `utf8mb4_general_ci` y en la tabla `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` para el `COLLATE`

---

### Conexión a la base de datos:

Usualmente en mi caso uso [PDO para las conexiones](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php) a la base de datos y en la conexión hago una serie de declaraciones para mantener y forzar el uso de UTF8 y evitar algún tipo de problema con php:

```php
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=tu_host;dbname=tu_base_de_datos;charset=utf8mb4", tu_usuario, tu_contraseña);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$conn->beginTransaction();
$conn->exec("set names utf8mb4");

.... //transacciones a ejecutar con exec ...

$conn->commit();
```

---

### El editor (IDE):

También es importante que tus archivos estén declarado como [UTF-8 SIN BOM](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-utf8-bom.es.html)

---

**Nota:** valida que los datos en no muestren caracteres extraños cuando haces el backup... ya que no importa todo lo anterior si los datos ya están corruptos.

Comment: disculpa pero tengo configurada mi base de datos en utf8_spanish_ci esto me generaría algún problema? si no esta en utf8mb4?

Comment: compatibilidad a largo plazo ...